# MIME Type error: Failed to copy main.js, runtime.js, etc files to sub-locations

Tags: angular, nginx, dockerfile, mime-types, angularbuild

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwXje.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh5ox.png)

---

We have Angular Localization in our App, we set up the Nginx.Default.Conf with different locations such as "Location /en-US/ {...}"  "Location /zh-CN/ {...}" . When the app builds, it generates sub-folders based on the locales specified in angular.json;
In the PRD server, it shows blank page sometimes and has the following error on console : "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript moule script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". "
When this happens we found that there were some files missing in source such as main.js, runtime.js and so on which were causing the [MIME Type ERROR]. Attached some pictures of the error and screenshot of source.

The issue only happen intermittently on the server and most of the time the application works fine. I'm thinking it could be an issue with DockerFile on the UI; In the dockerfile, we were copying everything under /src/dist to other sub-locations. Or could be an issue in angular.json .